# How to parse cookies in HTTPClient?

Tags: ruby, parsing, cookies, httpclient

In the below script I access a website which does many redirects and I need to know the URL/port of the last redirect.

```
cookie_file = Tempfile.new('cookie_jar.txt')
client.set_cookie_store(cookie_file)
client.set_auth(nil, user, pass)
client.ssl_config.verify_mode = nil

r = client.get(uri, :follow_redirect => true)
r = client.get_content(uri, :follow_redirect => true)

pp client.cookie_manager.jar
```

Looking at the cookies I can see from the second cookie that this time is was `https://example.com:65003`. If I try again then it will be a different port.

**Question**

How can I parse a HTTPClient cookie?

```
[#<HTTP::Cookie:name="ASPSESSIONIDQGDSCTSA",
value="DBEHBGICIKNNIBBMNAMGIMFG", domain="example.com",
for_domain=false, path="/", secure=true, httponly=false, expires=nil,
max_age=nil, created_at=2017-04-12 20:09:58 +0200,
accessed_at=2017-04-12 20:09:58 +0200 
origin=https://example.com/bwtem/?follow_redirect=true>,

#<HTTP::Cookie:name="ASPSESSIONIDSGAQARRD",
value="APJDHADDOHENHCCHOLLMAHNJ", domain="example.com",
for_domain=false, path="/", secure=true, httponly=false, expires=nil,
max_age=nil, created_at=2017-04-12 20:09:57 +0200,
accessed_at=2017-04-12 20:09:58 +0200 
origin=https://example.com:9000/auth/?id=7C05C91D24C4A798230A29FD28C587F3&target=https://example.com:65003&>]
```

Comment: Cookies are typically salted/encrypted/signed so unless you have the secret you won't be able to decrypt it.

Comment: It is the value of `target` I am looking for which is plain text. So the question is how to access it.

Comment: You mean you want to get the `target` query param from the value of `origin`?

Comment: Yes, in this case I want to end up with `https://example.com:65003` in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the URI module:

```
origin
=> "https://example.com:9000/auth/?id=7C05C91D24C4A798230A29FD28C587F3&target=https://example.com:65003&"
URI.decode_www_form(URI.parse(origin).query).to_h["target"]
=> "https://example.com:65003"
```